# Add random number to cell of matrices

Tags: matlab, random, cell

I have a cell, `A` of size 1 by 625. i.e.

`A = { A1, A2, ..., A625}`,

where each of the 625 elements of the cell `A` are 3D matrices of the same size, 42 by 42 by 3.

---

**Problem 1**

Since the entries of my matrices represent concentration of red blood cells which are of very small values and I cannot simply work with `randn`.

For each of the matrix, I try with this command, e.g.:

`A1 = A1 .*(1 + randn(42,42,3)/100)`

I try with dividing by `100` to minimize the possibility of very negative number (e.g. `1.234e-6`) but I cannot eliminate this possibility.

Also, is there any quick way to add different `randn(42,42,3)` to different 625 matrices. `A + randn(42,42,3)` won't work because it is adding the same set of random numbers.

---

**Problem 2**

I want to make 30 copies of the cell `A` by adding random numbers to each of entries of the 625 matrices. That is, I want to obtain a cell, `Patients` which is a cell of 1 by 30 and each of the cell element is another cell element of 625 matrices.

```
Patients = A % Initialization. I have 30 patients.

for i = 1 : 30;
   Patients = { Patients, Patients + `method from problem 1`};
end
```

I have tried to make my problems clear. I appreciate so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

```
% optional: initialize the random number generator to the current time. T
rng('shuffle');
A = cell(625);
A = cellfun( @(x) rand(42,42,3), A ,'UniformOutput', false)
```

note the differences between 'rand', 'randn', 'rng'

*from the MATLAB documentation:*

> rng('shuffle') seeds the random number generator based on the current time. Thus, rand, randi, and randn produce a different sequence of numbers after each time you call rng.

rand = Uniformly distributed random numbers -> no negative values [0, 1]

randn = Normally distributed random numbers

If you want to generate numbers in a special interval *(from the MATLAB documentation)*:

> In general, you can generate N random numbers in the interval [a,b] with the formula r = a + (b-a).*rand(N,1).

**Problem 2:**

I highly recommend you to build a struct with your 30 cells. This will facilitate the indexing/looping later significantly! You can name the struct fields after your patients, so you will have less trouble keeping track of them.

You can also build an cell-array. This is the easiest way for indexing.

In both cases: do preallocation of the memmory! *(MATLAB stores variables coherent in your memory. If the variable grows, MATLAB might have to relocate the variable...)*

```
% for preallocation + initialization in one step:
A = cell(625);
Patients.Peter = cellfun( @(x) rand(42,42,3), A ,'UniformOutput', false);
Patients.Tom = cellfun( @(x) rand(42,42,3), A ,'UniformOutput', false);

% loop through the struct like this
FldNms = fieldnames( Patients );
for i = 0:length(Patients)
     Patients.(FldNms{i}) = % do whatever you like
end
```

If you prefer an array:

```
% preallocation:
arry = cell(30);
for i = 1:length(array)
     arry(i) = { cellfun( @(x) rand(42,42,3), A ,'UniformOutput', false) };
end
```

This is a lot of wild indexing and you will get a lot of trouble by using (),{} and [] for indexing.

Think again if you need a cell array in the first place. An array of 625 matrices might suit you as well. Data structure can significantly affect the performance, the readability and your coding time!

Comment: Thank you for your advice of programming and I now tried to adopt it in my code.

Comment: A couple of comments, `rand` and `randn` are conceptually completely different. OP needs to be certain that a uniform distribution is acceptable. Secondly, your anonymous function should be ` @(x) x + rand(42,42,3)` otherwise instead of adding noise to images, you are just creating noise and discarding the original information completely.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, what about

```
cellfun(@(x)(x + randn(42,42,3)/100), A, 'uni', 0)
```

your second problem should (A) be a second question and (B) be trivial to solve once your first is done. Just drop the `Patients +` and your code should work correctly.

Comment: I tried with analogous simple problem: `A=reshape([1:9],3,3);`, `B = reshape([1:9],3,3);`, `C = {A,B};` and `D=cellfun(@(x)(x + randn(3,3)/100), C)`. It returns *Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.*

Comment: Right, forgot about that. But it's pretty much the clearest error possible. See edit (or google it)

Comment: Thank you again. It works by adding entry-wise random number. I tried many times that the random number produced wont be too negative if I did it by dividing 100. But, indeed, I intend to divide it by 10 because of real situation. Just wonder can we make it never be negative but the distribution of random numbers is still normal?

Comment: @nam that is impossible, if negative numbers are a major problem for you then perhaps you should be using a log-normal distribution instead.

Comment: Thanks again. The suggestion of the use of log-normal distribution is good.